# PyWinAuto.Application().connect(pid).window(windowName).send_keystrokes take way longer than keyboard.press()

Tags: python, background, delay, pywinauto, keystroke

I am trying make a keyboard recorder where you can record keys and play it. I have made the recording part, however when I send it to the focused window using keyboard.press() or keyboard.release(), it works perfectly find. However, when I use the method below;

```
windowName = 'some application name'
app = pywa.Application().connect(process=pid)
appRunning = app.window(title=windowName)
appRunning.send_keystrokes("{LEFT down}") for example, it would take 3~4times longer than            keyboard.press('LEFT').
```

For example, since I press down LEFT and press down 'a' and release 'a', it will be executed with big delay.
I have tried executing each key stroke by each but did not work either. I tried searching for it but there weren't a lot of details on pywinauto with send_keystrokes().